# broadcasting arrays and summation without temporary matrix allocations in Julia

Tags: julia

I need to perform a calculation of the form:

```
A = reshape(big_mat,m1,1,1,n1,n2,n3)
B = reshape(big_mat,1,m1,n1,1,n2,n3)
C = reshape(another_mat,m1,m1,n1,n1,1,1)
D = sum(A.*B.*C,dims=(5,6))
```

A.*B.*C is creating a temporary big matrix of size(m1,m1,n1,n1,n2,n3).  Given that D is only of size(m1,m1,n1,n1), is there a more efficient procedure of doing this summation without invoking for-loops?

Comment: I'd actually encourage the use of for loops here, if it is easier to express. We tend to avoid loops because of how slow they are in e.g., numpy, but for loops really are fast in Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask the computer to write the loops for you. `@einsum D[a,b,c,d] := mat[a,d,e,f] * mat[b,c,e,f] * another[a,b,c,d]` will write 6 nested `for` loops, summing over `e,f` which do not appear on the left.

`@tullio` will do the same, and add tiled memory access (and multi-threading) which should be a bit faster.

```
julia> using Einsum, Tullio, BenchmarkTools

julia> let
         n = 25
         big_mat = rand(n,n,n,n)
         another_mat = rand(n,n,n,n)
         D1 = @btime let n = $n
           A = reshape($big_mat,     n,1,1,n, n,n)
           B = reshape($big_mat,     1,n,n,1, n,n)
           C = reshape($another_mat, n,n,n,n, 1,1)
           D = sum(A.*B.*C,dims=(5,6))
         end
         D2 = @btime @einsum D[a,b,c,d] := $big_mat[a,d,e,f] * $big_mat[b,c,e,f] * $another_mat[a,b,c,d]
         D3 = @btime @tullio D[a,b,c,d] := $big_mat[a,d,e,f] * $big_mat[b,c,e,f] * $another_mat[a,b,c,d]
         D1 ≈ D2 ≈ D3
       end
  min 462.545 ms, mean 494.505 ms (20 allocations, 1.82 GiB)
  min 213.126 ms, mean 214.412 ms (3 allocations, 2.98 MiB)
  min 80.585 ms, mean 80.785 ms (53 allocations, 2.98 MiB)
true

julia> 2.98 * 25^2  # memory 2.98 MiB -> 1.82 GiB
1862.5

julia> @macroexpand1 @einsum D[a,b,c,d] := mat[a,d,e,f] * mat[b,c,e,f] * another[a,b,c,d]
quote  # this will print the loops
```